# how to form this UI

Tags: android, arrays, dialog

i want to show String Array from arrays.xml file to a **Custom dialog box** as in the following figure

. [image]

how to get this UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple solution...

```
private  int position=0;
    private void showDialog()
    {

        //For Default selection
    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Title");

    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(R.array.string_array,position,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
            position=which;

        }
    });
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
            String str=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.string_array)[position];
            Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "You are Selected:"+str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    builder.show();
    }
```

**String-Array:**

```
<resources>
     <string-array name="string_array">
        <item>Android</item>
        <item>Black Berry</item>
        <item>Iphone</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 2):

For creating dialogs like this,you just need to go through http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList. It is well explained there.

Answer (score 1):

use spinner Widget.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/binding.html

Answer (score 0):

thats how,

```
final String[] items = {"a", "b", "c"};

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
.setTitle("Pick")
.setSingleChoiceItems(, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}).show()
```